# Cloudendure to migrate VM to GCP

Tags: virtual-machines

I'm using Cloudendure to migrate VM to GCP. Learnt that Cloudendure is deprecating, is there any shutdown schedule for it ?

Regards,

Henry Kwong

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not deprecated, it was acquired by AWS, and as such supports migration to AWS only. We had a similar concern regarding migrations to Azure, and was told any existing customers will be supported, but new take-ons will be to AWS only.